# Attach markers to a bezier line and then "Pull" it straight with Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, geography, cartography

I have a bezier curve that I've used to trace the curve of a stream on a map.  At points along the stream I have objects that mark the location of data.  Is there anyway to attach the objects to the stream-curve and then straighten the curve?

I'd like to have this in order to create a river profile and also measure the distance between different pieces of data (some markers are elevation, and some are other data).

Before:

[image]

After:
[image]
... In my image, all of the markers should be evenly placed along the line, they just aren't perfectly placed in the version I made by hand.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. What research have you done (so we don't duplicate your effort, and to show us that you've at least tried yourself before asking). Why were the results unsatisfactory to you? Have you had a go at some code yourself? (even just pseudo-code)? If so, can you please edit your question and put it into your question? (it's much easier for us to help you if you already have some code - even if it's not working).

Comment: I believe both questions have a negative answer.

You could probably program an extension for flattening a polyline along a given direction.

Attaching markers to nodes is probably not so easy, such associations are not native to SVG I believe.